# Box visible on hover then staying visible after moving mouse to another box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making sort of a drop down list but more of a button, and i needs to be able to look good. I have almost got every thing I need but when i move the mouse onto the box that appears (drop down list), it disapears. This is what I have so far;

**html**

```
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="content">content here</div>
  <div id="box1"></div>
  <div id="content1">content here</div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="content2">content here</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: blue;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 11vw;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$("#box").hover(
  function() {
    $("#content").slideDown(); //.show();
  },
  function() {
    $("#content").fadeOut(); //hide();
  }
);

$("#content").hover(
  function() {
    $("#content").show(); //.show();
  },
  function() {
    $("#content").fadeOut(); //hide();
  }
);
```

Anything I am doing wrong, better ways to do this or a link to an existing question that already answers this would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help! got it working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is exactly what you wanted.

```
$("#box, #content").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $("#content").slideDown(); //.show();
})
.on("mouseleave", function() {
  if (!$("#content").is(":hover"))
    $("#content").fadeOut(); //hide();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kvbvLy4d/

Answer (score 3):

You could also achieve this without any Javascript / JQuery by animating the `height` of the content with CSS.

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: blue;
}

#box:hover + #content, #content:hover {
  height: 10vw;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 11vw;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 0;
  background-color: red;
   -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="content">content</div>
  <div id="box1"></div>
  <div id="content1">content</div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="content2">content</div>
</div>
```